# Power of existential types

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory, type-systems

It is well known that simply typed lambda calculus becomes much more expressive if you allow **universal types**, as in Girards system F. Thus, for example, you can encode the booleans as forall a. a -> a -> a and the integers as forall a. a -> (a-> a) -> a and furthermore, you can encode all logical operators and primitive recursive functions as well.

What happens if you use the dual concept, that of **existential types**? Can you encode any of the above structures? (It doesnt seem so) Can you encode *any* other interesting structure?

Comment: Have you considered types of the form $(\forall x.a) \rightarrow b$?

Comment: It is well known that existential types help one encode the concept of *encapsulation*, e.g. $\exists X. (X \rightarrow 1)\times(\mathrm{Int}\rightarrow X)$ could encode an `Int` container with an "increment" operation. See e.g. https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/44501.45065

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Universal types can be used to encode the *least fixed point*, while dually, existential types can be used to encode the *greatest fixed point*. For example, consider $F(X) = 1 + A \times X$, then the least fixed point of $F$ is the type of lists (of $A$). It is encoded by $\forall X. (F(X) \to X) \to X$. Expanding this you get
$$ \begin{aligned}
\forall X. (F(X) \to X) \to X &= \forall X. ((1 + A \times X) \to X) \to X \\
&= \forall X. (X \times (A \to X \to X)) \to X \\
&= \forall X. X \to (A \to X \to X) \to X \\
\end{aligned} $$
The dual notion here is *potentially infinite lists*, encoded by $\exists X. X \times (X \to F(X))$. Similarly if $F(X) = 1 + X \times X$ you get potentially infinite binary trees, etc.

Another interesting interaction is the relation between $\forall$ and $\exists$. We have $(\exists X. F(X)) \to Y$ is isomorphic to $\forall X. F(X) \to Y$, and with parametricity there are more interesting isomorphisms.

Comment: The duality between $\forall$  and $\exists$ becomes even more clear when you generalise from functions to message passing. Then it becomes
a clear input/output duality, see [Genericity and the $\pi$-calculus](https://users.sussex.ac.uk/~mfb21/publications/fossacs03/fossacs03.pdf)
with many message-passing parametricity properties. (Sorry for self-cite!) See also lots of subsequent work on polarised linear logic and session types.